# JSF 2 - page access depending on user role

Tags: java, web-applications, authentication, jsf-2

Currently using: JBoss 6 (Development on GlassFish 3.1), JSF 2.0, form-based authentication with JAAS (no "public" pages, everything needs authentication).

The web application provides two different search pages (like `search1.jsf` and `search2.jsf`), accessible from `index.jsf`, but for users which do not belong to a special role with additional rights, search2.jsf must not be accessible.

The "standard" way to protect search2.jsf would be a configuration in `web.xml` which requires the special user role for this page. Are there other ways to protect the second search page dynamically, either based on a role or based on user-specific attributes, which do not introduce additional authentication frameworks or container-specific features?

Disabling the link in index.jsf which points to search2.jsf is easy, but users could enter the URL of the second search page in the browser to see it (so for the prototype I will adjust web.xml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Are there other ways to protect the second search page dynamically, either based on a role or based on user-specific attributes, which do not introduce additional authentication frameworks or container-specific features?*

You can use EL in `<ui:include>`. Create a public master `search.xhtml` page which includes either `search1.xhtml` or `search2.xhtml` depending on the user role.

E.g.

```xml
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/search#{request.isUserInRole('admin') ? 1 : 2}.xhtml" />
```

*(Those include files are put in `/WEB-INF` so that the client cannot request it directly)*

Then open the page by just `search.xhtml` instead.